# How can I extract string between two strings with maximum length?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a large block of text that comes from several merged PDFs. I want to get a section out. The issue is that sometimes a surrounding section is not filled, and this affects the end "string markers" in the block of text. Specifically, the end string differs depending on how one of the individual pdfs was filled out.

My idea for how to do this is to search for the two end strings, and impose a maximum number of words before telling the string extractor to move on. Here's what I've tried:

```r
my_text <- "NARRATIVE\nsome things happened here\nFROM:\nblah blah blah\n(HOME)\nNARRATIVE\nsomething else \n maybe long\nIMPRESSION:\nblah blah blah\n(HOME)\this keeps going and going until it finally finds\nFROM:"

tofind <- paste(c("NARRATIVE(.*?)\nIMPRESSION","NARRATIVE(.*?)\nFROM:"), collapse="|")
narrative <- as.list(str_extract_all(my_text, regex(tofind, dotall = TRUE)))
```

This unfortunately only executes the first argument of "tofind". I want:

```r
whatIwant <- c("some things happened here", "something else \n maybe long")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```r
tofind <- paste(c("NARRATIVE(.*?)(\nFROM|IMPRESSION)"))
```

which finds the first occurrence of FROM or IMPRESSION to stop the match.